# springdoclet usage?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

is springdoclet use to generate bean defination xml files?  servlet-config.xml..etc ?

i trying to find out what is the different springdoclet compared to spring roo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) is a framework similar to grails, but written in java. It has different purpose comparing to springdoclet.

Also, see [user guide for roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html)